80's movie where they can freeze/unfreeze time
This is an early 80's movie that is a romantic comedy (I think). I really only remember one scene. It takes place in a restaurant. There are a few people who have the power to freeze and unfreeze time (by saying "freeze" or "unfreeze"). I want to say that one is the devil, and the others are angels. 
In the scene, the devil freezes time, and puts people or things in various situations where the outcome won't be positive when time unfreezes (for example: I remember him putting a man's hand down the top of a woman's blouse). The angels try to stop him, and an argument ensues, with the devil freezing time, and the angels unfreezing time in rapid succession. Suddenly, a thunderstorm erupts in the restaurant (God's wrath?) during a freeze. When time unfreezes, everyone in the restaurant is soaked and shocked. The explanation from the restaurant is a possible broken water main.
Sorry, I don't remember much else of the movie, but that scene stuck with me for the last 30 years.

Two of a Kind starring John Travolta and Olivia Newton John.  1983. The scene you are describing can be seen in the YouTube video at about 35 minutes. The scene is almost exactly as you described. 
